# How to convert this date value returned by WMI

Tags: powershell, datetime, wmi

I run this PowerShell script to query for certificate bound to SQL server:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement14' -Class SecurityCertificate | select name,expirationdate
```

It properly returns the certificate's subject and expiration date as:

```
name                        expirationdate
----                        --------------
servername.domain.com       31052014
```

However, I don't know what format that date is in as the certificate shows expiration as ‎`Thursday, ‎August ‎17, ‎2023 2:34:27 AM`

I've googled but found no results for the appropriate type of date that's being returned and how to convert to [datetime]. How can I understand this so that I can convert it and use it for comparisons?

Comment: PowerShell conversion `[datetime]::FromFileTime(([uint64]31052014 -shl 32))`

Answer (score 1):

A value of `31052014` represents the date+time `2023-08-15T19:08:23`.

### TL;DR: Run this interactive JS snippet to convert WMI `SecurityCertificate` `uint32` values to human-readable date-times:

1. Click "Show code snippet" below.
2. Scroll-down to the big blue "Run code snippet" button and click it.
3. Then enter the number (e.g. `31052014`) into the input-box that appears and click the button to convert it.

```js
function convertSqlServerCertificateExpirationToDateTime( value ) {

     //debugger;

      if( typeof value !== 'number' || value < 0 ) throw new Error( "Invalid `value` argument. Should be an integer number somewhere around ~30000000." );

     const epoch = new Date( /*y:*/ 1601, /*m:*/ 0, /*d:*/ 1, /*h:*/ 0, /*m:*/ 0, /*s:*/ 0, /*ms:*/ 0 ); // JS uses 0 for January instead of 1.

     const unitsPerDay   = 0.004970966;
     const days          = value * unitsPerDay;
     const secondsPerDay = 86400;
     const addSeconds    = days * secondsPerDay;

//   const secondsSinceEpoch = value * 430;

     const t = new Date( epoch.getTime() );
     t.setSeconds( t.getSeconds() + addSeconds );
     
     console.log( "Value %o corresponds to %o", value, t );
     
     return t;
 }
 
 function doConvert() {
 
     const inputValue = document.getElementById('wmiDateTime').valueAsNumber;
     
     console.log( 'inputValue: %o', inputValue );
     
     const dt = convertSqlServerCertificateExpirationToDateTime( inputValue );
     
     document.getElementById('output1').textContent = dt.toLocaleString();
     document.getElementById('output2').textContent = dt.toISOString();
 }
```

```css
output {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: purple;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0; }

label { display: block; }
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>WMI uint32 datetime converter</legend>
    
    <label>
        <span>Integer value:</span>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="wmiDateTime" />
    </label>
    
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="doConvert()">Convert</button>
    </div>
    
    <output id="output1"></output>
    <output id="output2"></output>

</fieldset>
```

---

#### Backstory

This interested me, so I created a new self-signed certificate and jumped through the hoops to get it working with SQL Server 2022....

- SQL Server Configuration Manager for SQL Server 2022 **does now** show the expiration date (but not the time, and it's local-time not UTC, **gah**).
- However, using a WMI CIM browser tool, such as [wmiexplorer](https://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm) shows the `uint32` values that you're describing:

  - [image]
  - [image]
- The certificate I generated has the following fields (as shown in Certificates.msc and `certutil`:

  - `NotBefore`:

    - `2022-10-07 18:59:44`
    - `30988985`
  - `NotAfter`:

    - `2023-04-07 19:09:44`
    - `31025599`
- The difference between those two integer values is `36614`.
- The difference between those two dates is 182 days, 0 hours, 10 minutes.

  - Or `182d + 0h + (10/1440)m` or **182.00694** days.
- `36614 / 182.00694 == 201.168`, therefore 1 day (i.e. 24 hours) == `201.168` *mystery-units*.
- Now let's find the epoch:

  - `30988985 / 201.168 == 154,045.3`
  - i.e. `30988985` is 154,045 days after the epoch.
  - As `30988985` is `2022-10-07 18:59:44`, the epoch is therefore that date+time, minus 154,045.3 days.

    - Which is sometime around **1601-01-02 11:47:44**.
    - ***heeeeyyy*** that date looks kinda familiar... **1601-01-01 00:00** [is the Win32 clock epoch!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10849717/159145) - so let's attribute the extra day to rounding error.
  - Also, `182.00694 / 36614 == 0.00497`.

    - i.e. Each incremental integer value in `expirationdate` corresponds to `0.00497` days - or **430 seconds** (approx).
- Therefore the conversion function (in JavaScript) is:

  ```
  function convertSqlServerCertificateExpirationToDateTime( value ) {
       if( typeof value !== 'number' || value < 0 ) throw new Error( "Invalid `value` argument. Should be an integer number somewhere around ~30000000." );

       const epoch = new Date( /*y:*/ 1601, /*m:*/ 0, /*d:*/ 1, /*h:*/ 0, /*m:*/ 0, /*s:*/ 0, /*ms:*/ 0 ); // JS uses 0 for January instead of 1.

       const unitsPerDay   = 0.004970966;
       const days          = value * unitsPerDay;
       const secondsPerDay = 86400;
       const addSeconds    = days * secondsPerDay;

       const t = new Date( epoch.getTime() );
       t.setSeconds( t.getSeconds() + addSeconds );
       return t;
  }
  ```

---

### Pain....

- [SSL Certificate missing from dropdown in SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817627/ssl-certificate-missing-from-dropdown-in-sql-server-configuration-manager)
- [How to set key spec or KEYEXCHANGE property when generating a self-signed certificate using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614138/how-to-set-key-spec-or-keyexchange-property-when-generating-a-self-signed-certif)
- [CertUtil Import pfx failed: NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642667/certutil-import-pfx-failed-nte-not-supported)
- [New-SelfSignedCertificate on Win2012 r2 has less parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924054/new-selfsignedcertificate-on-win2012-r2-has-less-parameters)

**TL;DR:** run this in an elevated PowerShell locally on the box running SQL Server 2022:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $selfSignedRootCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName sql2022.corp.example.com -notafter (Get-Date).AddMonths(6) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage CertSign,CRLSign,DigitalSignature -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048 -KeyUsageProperty All -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA' -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256' -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'
```

- The `-KeySpec KeyExchange` option is **very important**.
- Use `-DnsName` not `-Subject`, and use the FQDN name.

---

Answer (score 1):

It looks like high 32 bit word of [64 bit win32 filetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime)

Here is sample js to convert from it to normal values:

```js
function fromHighW32(value) {
  let bv = BigInt(value);
  bv = bv << 32n;
  bv = bv - 116444736000000000n; // start of unix epoch
  bv = bv / 10000n; // convert from 100n to millis
  return new Date(parseInt(bv.toString(), 10));
}

console.log(fromHighW32(31052014).toUTCString());
console.log(fromHighW32(30988985).toUTCString());
console.log(fromHighW32(31025599).toUTCString());
```

though exact numbers are a little bit different from your output and output from @Dai answer, it is because we don't see low word, so the values are +/- 429.5 seconds (~7 minutes)

Comment: Upvoted - props for distilling it down like that. 